# Using devexpress TreeList as column editor in GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

is it possible using devexpress TreeList as inplace editor in gridView column ?
i want to select categories and save them, for each row in products tables.
i dont know how to do it.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "[How to create an analog of GridLookUpEdit with TreeList in a popup window](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E4319.aspx)" KB-article.